# How to tell if a player can read NTFS or Pal

Tags: htpc, blu-ray

I'm considering picking up a box set DVD t.v. show which uses Region 0 (The IT Crowd, Seasons 1 - 4).   I know there are regions for DVD (Region 1 = USA, Region 2 = Europe), but this DVD set is Region 0 (region free).

The only question I have is, how can I tell if this player can read both NTSC and PAL formats?  It is installed in my HTPC which is connected to my TV via HDMI.